# Setting custom color on UINavaigationBar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to set color of UINavigationBar with particular opacity and alpha? I've tried a lot things, but I still can't get what I want. The color is 7, 4, 43 for RGB and 0,4 for opacity and alpha.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
[navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:7.0/255.0 green:4.0/255.0 blue:43.0/255.0 alpha:0.4]];
```

And in Swift:

```
navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 7.0, green: 4.0, blue: 43.0, alpha: 0.4)
```

Comment: but what to do with the opacity?